# The term `function declaration` is defined in §7/9 (N4140), but it isn't defined as a grammar production. Why?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, function-declaration

In §7/9 you'll find the definition of a *function declaration*:

> If the *decl-specifier-seq* contains no typedef specifier, the
>   declaration is called a *function declaration* if the type associated
>   with the name is a function type (8.3.5) and an *object declaration*
>   otherwise.

In §7/1 you can find the definition of the grammar-production *declaration*, but there is no *function-declaration* nominated in there, as part of this definition. In other words, how would one classify `function declaration` in the C++ grammar?

Comment: I'd say it's a sub-categorization of `declaration` . It's not a syntactic category, since the phrase "function declaration" is generally used without italics, contrary to 1.6p1, which suggests that the definition is needed for expository purposes, in order to express constraints which can not be, or cannot conveniently be expressed as part of a CFG.

Comment: An important part of (most? all?) programming languages is that the grammar does not define the language.  Things that do not match the grammar are not in the language (generally, there may be an exception), but the standard puts more restrictions on valid programs than the grammar does, and it can even define terms that do not show up as terms in the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that paragraph talks about *init-declarators*, I take it to apply to a *simple-declaration* in which there is an *init-declarator-list*. You can see that this is not entirely correct

```
// clearly, this is not the declaration of an object, so it should
// not be called an "object declaration", but 7p9 does say so
int &a = x;

struct A {
   // AFAICS 7p9 should also apply here, but there is no init-declarator
   // here, but a member-declarator. 9.2 also doesn't delegate to 7p9.
   typedef int a;
};
```

A consequence is that the following also contains a function declaration, but that declaration declares not a function.

```
template<typename T> void f();
```

In summary, I think there is some clarification on this text desired in the spec.

Comment: Now I can understand clearly that a `function declaration` is a `simple-declaration`. Thanks.